# $A\in\mathcal{S}^+_n,A={}^tMM$

Tags: matrices

How can I prove that any symmetric positive matrix $A\in\mathcal{S}^+_n(\mathbb{R})$ can be written $A={}^tMM$ where $M$ is an invertible matrix ?

This is probably a duplicate, but I have not been able to find the corresponding previous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the [Choleski decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition).

You basically write all the different equations, and prove that they always have some solution.